# Creating a table categorization with has_many :through for categories and posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite3-ruby

Hey guys I'm doing a has_many :through association in ruby on rails.
And I want some help if it's ok with my example.
So I pretend to do categories for Posts. 
Supposing I already have builded the class post.
So for create the database for categories I pretend to do like these:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def change
    create_table :categorizations do |t|
      t.belongs_to :post, index: true
      t.belongs_to :category, index: true
      t.integer :position

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :categorizations, [:product_id, :category_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

It's ok these index's for boost the database?

Comment: Defining a column using `t.belongs_to` will automatically create an index for you. And yes, that is a generally a good idea for database performance.

Comment: Nice, thank's for reply XML Slayer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that multi-column index that you've defined at the bottom:

```
add_index :categorizations, [:product_id, :category_id], unique: true
```

is valid. *But* it's also unnecessary and likely less performant than the single column indexes that you have individually defined on `product_id` and `category_id`.